# Python A part of code is not being executed

Tags: python, testcase

I have this class which gives me output of "I am in level 1" but doesn't out "I am in level 2" so I assume get_full_name(self) part isn't being executed any help?

```
class UserTest(TestCase):

    user = UserFactory()

    def test_user_login_client(self):
        self.client.login(username=self.user.email, password=self.user.password)
        print "I am in level 1"

    def get_full_name(self):
        print "I am in level 2"
        full_name = user.full_name()

        return full_name
```

Comment: This code won't even parse with python, your class definition is empty.

Comment: please elaborate ? am new to python

Comment: Python expects an indented block under your class definition. Without that, the code will not parse. Does the indentation of this example match the code that you are testing?

Comment: Indeed. The indentation of the code you posted cannot match what you are running to receive an output of "I am in level 1". It is unclear what exact output you want, so I cannot be of more help without a clearer problem statement. Indeed, print "I am in level 2" will not be executed since it's inside a function definition, one that is never called.

Comment: couldn't set the indentation of code while posting the question fixed it now n that's how it looks like in my code copy n yes there is code above this specific section of code in file which deals with all import and stuff my only problem here is i cannot get code below def get_full_name(self): executed n cant figure out why

Comment: Well, how do you get the code in `test_user_login_client` to execute? "i am in level 1" is currently inside of that function and won't print without the function being called. If you actually call `get_full_name` it will print your level 2 message.

Comment: well i am writing tests for django and using factory boy so calling my test does execution and does return me results of test_user_login_client(self) but its not executing second function and returns the test as successful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The convention is to prefix the test functions with `test_`

You need to rename `get_full_name` to `test_get_full_name`